# webView in android Notification in android

Tags: android, webview, notifications

How can I use Web View in notification layout

As I am using A image view and text View can i use a web view in layout ??
To support different HTML tags send in push notification .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry you can not use a web view in a notification (or in RemoteViews at all).

Comment: and sir if some one adds some tags which are not supported by textview so how would we manage them.

Comment: @stiffler: You remove those tags, limiting yourself to ones supported by `TextView`. Unfortunately, the list of things supported by `Html.fromHtml()` is undocumented, though [I reverse-engineered a list for Android 2.1 a while ago](http://commonsware.com/blog/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html).